# Dbal insert returning id

Tags: php, database, doctrine, dbal

I'm making an insert and I would like to have a return with the insert id.
How do I get this return?

Example of how I'm doing the insert.

```
$query= Database::connection();
$query->insert('test')
->setValue('title', '?')
->setParameter(0, $values['title']);
return $query->executeQuery();
```

I'm using doctrine dbal querybuilder 3.6.6

I need the insert id to be returned to use this id in another insert.